# cabal install gving errror as LICENSE: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I have cabal version:

```
❯ cabal --version
cabal-install version 3.0.0.0
compiled using version 3.0.0.0 of the Cabal library
```

Here is what I am doing.

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
cabal init
cabal install
```

and I am getting an error:

```
LICENSE: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: After you do `cabal init`, what files exist?

Comment: CHANGELOG.md  Main.hs  foo.cabal  Setup.hs

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid it does not include LICENSE file

Comment: Just to be sure: `cabal install` will install the executable in your system, by making it available from (by default) `~/.cabal/bin`. Is that really what you want to do? If all you need is building and running your project as you develop it, `cabal build` and `cabal run` should suffice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When ran in the manner you describe, `cabal init` warns that:

```
Warning: unknown license type, you must put a copy in LICENSE yourself.
```

Without a `LICENSE` file, certain commands won't work properly (cf., for instance, [cabal issue #6744](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/6744)). You should either create a `LICENSE` file, or pick one of the licenses Cabal knows about by specifying it through the `-l` option of `cabal init`.

Comment: Understood! Thanks for answer.